# How to specify a masterpage on a sharepoint web part page

Tags: 2007, development, web-part-page, web-part-gallery

I have this code courtesy of Alex Angas in [Programmatically instantiate a web part page in Sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979635/programmatically-instantiate-a-web-part-page-in-sharepoint). I already posted this question on stackoverflow but didn't get any answer so I decided to transfer my question here.

In my **_catalogs/masterpage** folder, I have 2 masterpages namely:

1. default.master
2. mobilepage.master

I wanted to modify the code below in such a way that I could set the masterpage instead of **default.master**, I will make it to **mobilepage.master** which is created specifically for **Mobile.aspx**

This code below creates a mobile.aspx file inside the document library. My only problem is how to specify the masterpage of the mobile.aspx?

```
string newFilename = "Mobile.aspx";
string templateFilename = "spstd1.aspx";
string hive = SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath("TEMPLATE\\1033\\STS\\DOCTEMP\\SMARTPGS\\");
FileStream stream = new FileStream(hive + templateFilename, FileMode.Open);
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sharepoint")){
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
    SPFolder libraryFolder = web.GetFolder("Document Library");
    SPFileCollection files = libraryFolder.Files;
    SPFile newFile = files.Add(newFilename, stream);
}}
```

Please help me modify the code above. I would gladly appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to set the master page for Mobile.aspx to be mobilepage.master?

Comment: yes :) hope you can help me

Answer (score 1):

I hope your Mobile.aspx is an Application Page. In application pages, you can set the master page either in the .aspx with the **MasterPageFile** attribute:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="ApplicationPage1.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="SharePointModalDialogDemo.Layouts.SharePointModalDialogDemo.ApplicationPage1"  
MasterPageFile="_catalogs/mobilemaster.master" %>
```

Or in the application page code behind, where your code may come to use:

```
this.Page.MasterPageFile = "custom master url";
```

Comment: Mobile.aspx is a webpart page, and it is created on the fly based on the web part page template. I don't think I can do that :( do you have any other option?